# Best practice for an optional return value

Tags: python, exception, coding-style, anti-patterns

Suppose a function cannot compute a valid return value. For example, a dictionary lookup may fail to find a key. What are the best practices for such a situation when a function returns one or no value?

**1. Return `None`:** For example, `dict.get()` is this pattern. The downside of this approach is that the client needs to check if the returned value is `None` and do something depending on it.

For example,

```py
def getprice(car: Car) -> Optional[int]:
    if ispriceless(car):
        return None
    return car.value

def client():
    average_car_price_on_market = mean(
        [getprice(car) for car in get_all_cars() if getprice(car) is not None]
    )
```

(of course, I don't have to call `getprice` twice but I just wanted to highlight the awkwardness)

**2. Use `yield`:** Basically this is like returning a list containing zero or one element. The above example would look like this:

```py
def getprice(car: Car) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    if not ispriceless(car):
        yield car.value

def client():
    average_car_price_on_market = mean(
        [price for car in get_all_cars() for price in getprice(car)]
    )
```

I find this one slightly easier to read but some people may say it is less explicit?

**3. Use an exception:** This is probably the most explicit approach but I wonder how people think about the overhead of exception handling; I have also seen arguments against using exceptions as control flows (for example, [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why))

Comment: This depends on what you're trying to achieve. If your program can handle priceless cars and you want the average price to not include those, then the filtering approach is appropriate. Also, what is the value of `car.value` when the car is priceless? If that attribute is `None`, you can simplify to `[car.value for get_all_cars() if car.value]`. If the attribute instead doesn't exist, you can use `getattr(car, 'value', None)`.

Comment: I'd say that there is no approved general strategy: it depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

> **1. Return `None`:** For example, `dict.get()` is this pattern. The downside of this approach is that the client needs to check if the returned
> value is None and do something depending on it.

Note that mentioned `.get` allow you to specify what should be provided for not present key. Therefore if you have power to get element *neutral* w.r.t. further processing you can skip checks, for example if you want to compute total you might do

```
data = {"A":100,"C":80}
total = sum(data.get(i,0) for i in ["A","B","C"])
print(total)
```

output

```
180
```

Comment: Yeah thank you for reminding me. Certainly returning a neutral value (I don't know if this is a widely accepted terminology) is an option. One caveat is that the appropriate neutral value depends on the downstream operation.